# Grails : Spring Security login/authenticate stopped working, what could have caused this?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I have a project that has been using the same plugin now for a while, the Spring Security Shiro plugin. Out of the blue the login/authenticate routine stopped working. What could have caused this? I have not made any changes to anything that could affect this.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you. Im in dire need.

Answer (score 0):

I cleared out my browser cookies and tried again, it worked.